# customized matplotlib colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

[image]

```
colors = ['white', '#FFFFBB', '#C3FDB8', '#B5EAAA', '#64E986', '#54C571', 
          '#4AA02C','#347C17','#347235','#25383C','#254117']
```

I made a plot using matplotlib (similar to a heatmap)
I would like to either :

1) make a legend using the colors I defined in the list or
2) is there anyway of automating it in matplotlib to create as beautiful as an effect in R?
the normal matplotlib color gradient is too "sharp" looking...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the [other colormaps](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps) -- it seems like "summer" is close to what you used, with white being null values.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple using [ListedColormap](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap):

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm  # color map
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

#dummy data
hm = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(5, 5))

#define colors
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['white', '#FFFFBB', '#C3FDB8', '#B5EAAA', '#64E986', '#54C571',
          '#4AA02C', '#347C17', '#347235', '#25383C', '#254117'])

#create plot frames
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,2, height_ratios=[6,2], width_ratios=[20,1],)
ax = plt.subplot(gs[0, 0])

#heatmap and colorbar
im = ax.pcolor(hm, cmap=cmap)
cbar = plt.colorbar(im, cax=plt.subplot(gs[1]))

plt.show()
```

[image: heatmap]